# Integrating Android (or Gradle) with Gitlab-CI

Tags: android, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab have recently integrated CI into the new version right now. Is there a better way to integrate android testing with gitlab-ci in order for it to work with gitlab? This would be great considering you can now do everything on one server

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've set up Gitlab CI to build android projects. [Here's a container that can build android](https://github.com/DariusL/android-drone/blob/master/Dockerfile). Memories of trying to run an emulator in a server are too painful, so I'd just stick with Robolectric or something similar. You'll probably have to tweak the container for the version of android you're building against. This setup uses a gradle installation, since I have trouble setting up proper caching.

```
variables:
  LIBRARY: "rxfirebaseandroid"

build:
  script:
    - gradle testDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $LIBRARY/build/outputs/aar/
```

Answer (score 0):

Building and unit testing work quite well. [Here's](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/) a tutorial that also includes functional tests using an emulator. For me, setting up the emulator has not worked (yet) but the other two were relatively pain-free.

Below I posted the .gitlab-ci.yml, which worked best for my android app. If you don't need the emulator, you could probably drop the before_script and of course the functional tests, and you'd be left with a very short config file. But whether or not the emulator works seems to depend on the [runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html) you use, so you might want to give it a shot.

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "25"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "25.0.2"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "25.2.3"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 libqt5widgets5
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
  - unzip -q android-sdk.zip
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD//platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/

unitTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ./gradlew test

functionalTests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - wget --quiet --output-document=android-wait-for-emulator https://raw.githubusercontent.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/0f497eb71291b52a703143c5cd63a217c8766dc9/community-cookbooks/android-sdk/files/default/android-wait-for-emulator
    - chmod +x android-wait-for-emulator
    - echo y | tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-x86-google_apis-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
    - echo no | tools/android create avd -n test -t android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK} --abi google_apis/x86
    - tools/emulator64-x86 -avd test -no-window -no-audio &
    - ./android-wait-for-emulator
    - adb shell input keyevent 82
    - ./gradlew cAT
```